# MSDN (Owner Drawn) Listbox control freeze after scrolling

Tags: c, winapi, scroll, listbox, msdn

I'm working on an Owner-Drawn Listbox Control that i managed to create and populate without errors.

Here's my problem :
***When i scroll it, the listbox and its parent window becomes unresponsive after scrolling for a few seconds.(with PgDown)***

Note that :

- There's a lot of items in it (more than 4k)
- The messages are still being processed, i can monitor them on the console and they are being sent and received. **Only difference is, WM_DRAWITEM is no longer sent...**
- The items of the listbox are added via LB_ADDSTRING

What i tried :

- Using the PeekMessage function instead of the GetMessage

-> Program crashes after the list is filled

- Redrawing the windows after the problem occurs (via a WM_LDOUBLECLICK event for example)

-> No effets

Code snippets :

- Window Procedure

  ```
  LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
      {
          HBRUSH Brush;
          HBRUSH BLANK_BRUSH;
          HBRUSH BLUE_BRUSH;
          Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(163, 255, 249));
          BLANK_BRUSH = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255, 255));
          BLUE_BRUSH = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0, 255));
          int tabs[13]={140,256,261,287,318,353,422,460,500,530,550,570,610};
          switch(msg)
          {
              HDC hdc ;
              PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
              PMEASUREITEMSTRUCT pmis;
              LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT Item;
              RECT rect ;
              rect.top=-50;
              rect.bottom=0;
              RECT rect2 ;
              rect.top=10;
              case WM_MEASUREITEM:
                  pmis = (PMEASUREITEMSTRUCT) lParam;
                  pmis->itemHeight = 17;
                  return TRUE;
              break;
              case WM_DRAWITEM:
                      Item = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
                      if (Item->itemState & ODS_FOCUS)
                      {
                          SetTextColor(Item->hDC, RGB(255,255,255));
                          SetBkColor(Item->hDC, RGB(0, 0, 255));
                          FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, (HBRUSH)BLUE_BRUSH);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          SetTextColor(Item->hDC, RGB(0,0,0));
                          SetBkColor(Item->hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                          FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, (HBRUSH)BLANK_BRUSH);
                      }
                      int len = SendMessage(Item->hwndItem , LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)Item->itemID, 0);
                          if (len > 0)
                          {
                              LPCTSTR lpBuff = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(TCHAR));
                              len = SendMessage(Item->hwndItem , LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)Item->itemID, (LPARAM)lpBuff);
                              if (len > 0) {
                                  TabbedTextOut(Item->hDC,Item->rcItem.left, Item->rcItem.top,(LPARAM)lpBuff,len,13,&tabs,140);
                              }
                          }
                      return TRUE;
              break;
              case WM_CLOSE:
                  DestroyWindow(hwnd);
              break;
              case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
                GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
                SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(230,50,2));
                SetBkMode(hdc,TRANSPARENT);
                FillRect(hdc,&ps.rcPaint,Brush);
                DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Liste des messages décodés: "), -1, &rect, DT_CENTER );
                DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Numéro d'engin (4xxxy): "), -1, &rect, DT_LEFT );
                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                return 0 ;
              case WM_DESTROY:
                  PostQuitMessage(0);
              break;
              case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                  return TRUE;
              break;
              default:
                  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
          }
         return 0;
  }
  ```
- Message Loop

```
    BOOL bRet;
           while (1)
            {
                bRet = GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0);
                if (bRet > 0)
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
                }
                else if (bRet == 0){
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("error\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return Msg.wParam;
```

- Window creation

  WNDCLASSEX wc;

  ```
  wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.style         = 0;
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
  wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
  wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
  wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

  RegisterClassEx(&wc);

  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,g_szClassName,"List of messages",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,0, 0, 1500, 1000,NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);

  if(hwnd == NULL)
  {
      return 0;
  }
      hwnd2 = CreateWindowEx(0,"LISTBOX" ,"Data",WS_CHILD |WS_HSCROLL |WS_VSCROLL |WS_BORDER|WS_THICKFRAME | LBS_USETABSTOPS | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_HASSTRINGS,15,70,1450,450,hwnd,(HMENU) NULL,hInstance,NULL);
  ```

It looks like there's a timer somewhere, and if a keyboard touch stays too long down, it somehow messes everything up...

Has someone encountered a problem like this before or could help me understand what is going on ?

Comment: Declare your brushes `static` and delete them in response to `WM_CLOSE`, that should be a quick fix to your problem...

Answer (score 3):

You have a significant GDI resource leak in your code.

At the top of your `WndProc` function you're creating three brushes, and you never delete them. These brushes are created **every time** your window processes a message.

You should only create the brushes when you actually need them for painting, and call `DeleteObject` to release them when you're done with them.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan,

I will try that asap.